# Php make dir using text name and rename upload file

Tags: php

Html sample code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
Company Name:<input type="text" name="company"/><br />
ClientName: <input type="text" name="ClientName"/><br />
<br />
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5120000" />
 Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
</body>
```

Sample Php code:

```
<?php

$file_name = $_POST['company'];
$random_digit = rand(0000,9999);
$new_file_name = $random_digit.$file_name;

$uploaddir = 'c:/temp/'.$new_file_name;
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo "<p>";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
echo "Upload failed";
}

echo "</p>";
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
echo '['.$new_file_name.']';
print "</pre>";
?>
```

I am having problem with the rename. It renames the file but it keeps the original name too.  So if I upload a file name joey.doc, it changes to random# = 4567, company name = whatever, file name = joey.doc  output = 4567whateverjoey.doc.   What I am looking for is for the file name to change to the random number append the company only = 4567whatever.doc. Later I will write code to create company name directory store all file from that company in their directory. Store the location tag in xml then pull up a table with to reference. the information. Plus I use the client name input box to decode what file go with what.

If writing xml is like asp.net C# I should have no problem

Comment: why are you appending the random number to the file name, it seems a bit illogical to do this given your requirement. Do you have access to the old file name i.e. are users downloading a file changing it then re-uploading it?

Comment: the file that is being upload will be a client's customer. So if they need to upload the client information file a second time it will rename the file and give it a number code. Health System HIPAA protection of the client identity. I figure it out, thanks any way.

Comment: I guess I didn't figure out. In ASP.Net C# I can rename a file before it upload to the path I set. I guess I can't do this with PHP or can I.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the old name again:

```
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
```

If you only want to append the extension have a look at [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
```

in particular just do some string manipulation on the basename(...) portion.
Basically, all you care about is the extension...and depending on your filename restrictions and desired robustness the answer could be easy, or a little bit tricky.

one example (so you get the idea):

```
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . '.' . split('.',basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']))[1];
```

or use built-in function [Pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Comment: Array deferencing is only possible as of PHP 5.4 which is currently a RC.

Comment: um...that doesn't seem right...pretty sure I access arrays all the time with the []...

Comment: That assumes the file name before the extension has no `.` characters in it. `pathinfo()` is much more reliable, and I know everybody *loves* inbuilt functions ; )

Comment: AGREED. :D
I was just showing that he had the flexibility to do string manipulation if he say wanted to keep more than just the extension, split on other characters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
$uploaddir = 'c:/temp/'.$new_file_name;
```

You add the new file name to the directory it's to be located in.
But in this line:

```
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
```

You also append the old name it was uploaded with to that string. You should do what @TimWolla suggested and find out about `pathinfo()` if you want to find just the extension.